# How to save Leaflet in R map as png or jpg file?

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet package to create maps in R. It works perfectly. I can export maps in R with simply Export, but I need to export maps from script in R. My simple code is:

```
png("test_png.png")
(m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles())
dev.off()
```

It works but... the output png file is white blank.

Comment: Thanx, but I was trying "print" and it doesn't works. The effect is the same: white image.

Comment: There's a reason it's not easy to do: Leaflet is a JavaScript library for building interactive maps for the web. If you want a static map, there are lots of R packages that make them. When you force it, you're almost always overriding someone's well-thought-out design choices, and will usually end up with a subpar product. Choose the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This very nice workaround emerged [in response to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508486/create-a-gif-from-a-series-of-leaflet-maps-in-r/33516902#33516902) asked a little later here on SO. Note that you are required to install [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to get the following code to work.

```
## install 'webshot' package
library(devtools)
install_github("wch/webshot")

## load packages
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(webshot)

## create map
m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles()

## save html to png
saveWidget(m, "temp.html", selfcontained = FALSE)
webshot("temp.html", file = "Rplot.png",
        cliprect = "viewport")
```

And here's the resulting image.

[image: map]

---

#### Update:

Now that **webshot** has been officially released on CRAN and with the introduction of `mapshot` in the **mapview** package, this manual workaround is no longer required. Now, the code simply goes like this:

```
library(mapview)

## 'leaflet' objects (image above)
m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles()
mapshot(m, file = "~/Rplot.png")

## 'mapview' objects (image below)
m2 <- mapview(breweries91)
mapshot(m2, file = "~/breweries.png")
```

[image: breweries]

Comment: I think that the `webshot()` function must still be used to store high resolution maps, despite the `mapview package`.