# Is it possible to change leaflet map screenshot size in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I found two answers concerning saving Leaflet Maps in shiny:

1. [How to save a leaflet map in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259716/how-to-save-a-leaflet-map-in-shiny/44261618)
2. [How to save Leaflet in R map as png or jpg file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336898/how-to-save-leaflet-in-r-map-as-png-or-jpg-file?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The core idea of them is to use `mapshot()` instead `webshot()`. In this case for setting screenshot size used `cliprect` parameter. It defines a clipping rectangle which matches the height & width from the viewing port. So, if `cliprect = 'viewport'`, **I thought, map on the screenshot will be looks like on my screen. But it isn't.**

I tryed to use code from examples above and they have given the same result.

That's why my question is: **Is it possible to change leaflet map screenshot size in R Shiny and if yes, how it can be done?**

[My screen in browser with map looks likes this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHvjl.png)

[I hope to get screenshot like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKOHb.png)

[But I got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpUVB.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** The original answer downloaded the map as rendered initially without taking user's interaction with the map into account. I updated my answer using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47988859/8099834) so the download reflects the map as it looks to the user.

1. Use js to get the current size of the map `div` (as based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37060206/8099834) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15615701/8099834))
2. Update the map based on [current zoom and map center](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html#inputsevents)
3. Change the size of the screenshot using `vwidth` and `vheight`

Example based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44261618/8099834) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47988859/8099834):

```
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # 1. js to get width/height of map div
  tags$head(tags$script('
                        var dimension = [0, 0];
                        $(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {
                        dimension[0] = document.getElementById("map").clientWidth;
                        dimension[1] = document.getElementById("map").clientHeight;
                        Shiny.onInputChange("dimension", dimension);
                        });
                        $(window).resize(function(e) {
                        dimension[0] = document.getElementById("map").clientWidth;
                        dimension[1] = document.getElementById("map").clientHeight;
                        Shiny.onInputChange("dimension", dimension);
                        });
                        ')),
  leafletOutput("map"),
  downloadButton("dl", "Download Map")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # reactive values to store map
  vals <- reactiveValues()

  # create base map  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    vals$base <- leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
      addTiles()
  })

  # create map as viewed by user
  observeEvent({
    input$map_zoom
    input$map_center
    }, {
      vals$current <- vals$base %>% 
        setView(lng = input$map_center$lng,
                lat = input$map_center$lat,
                zoom = input$map_zoom)
    }
  )

  # create download
  output$dl <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "map.png",

    content = function(file) {
      mapshot(vals$current, file = file,
              # 2. specify size of map based on div size
              vwidth = input$dimension[1], vheight = input$dimension[2])
    }
  )

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps to solve my problem. But now screenshots don't take into account map scale. How can I resolve it?

Comment: @ЯрославХромов good catch! I've updated the answer to address this. Let me know if it works for you!