# Exporting a PNG from a dygraph plot in Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dygraphs, shinyjs

I'm having difficulty exporting a PNG of a dygraph in a Shiny app.  I have been using [this script](http://cavorite.com/labs/js/dygraphs-export/dygraph-extra.js) following [the example](http://cavorite.com/labs/js/dygraphs-export/) and modifying it for Shiny.  I'm using the `shinyjs` library to pass my dygraph object to the client.  I'm running into the following error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'*

Here is a hopefully reproducible example:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(shinyjs)

js.png <- '
  shinyjs.exportPNG = function(params) {
    var defaultParams = {
      dygraph : null,
      img : null,
      userOptions : null,
    }
    params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);  

    var image = document.getElementById(params.img);
    Dygraph.Export.asPNG(params.dygraph, image);
  }
  '

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = js.png),
  actionButton('btn', 'Go'),
  includeScript('./www/dygraph-extra.js'),
  dygraphOutput("plot"),
  img(id = 'plot-static')
  )
)
```

server.R

```
library(dplyr)
library(xts)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    js$exportPNG(dygraph = dyplot.global, img = 'plot-static')
  })

  plot.data <- reactive({
    d <- airquality %>%
      mutate(Date = as.Date(paste('1973', Month, Day, sep = '-'))) %>%
      select(Date, Ozone, Temp) %>%
      arrange(Date)
    d.xts <- xts(d[,-1], order.by = d$Date)
  })

  output$plot <- renderDygraph({
    g <- dygraph(plot.data()) %>%
      dyRangeSelector()
    dyplot.global <<- g
    g
  })
})
```

I'm very novice with javascript, so please be gentle.  The actual plot and data are quite a bit more involved and I'm pretty invested in the interaction and features in dygraphs.  Thank you.

Comment: I think dygraph creates html document, so this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336898/how-to-save-leaflet-in-rstudio-map-as-png-or-jpg-file

Comment: Thanks @MLavoie.  That does work for exporting the dygraph as it initially looks when it is first loaded, but I would like to capture the view as the user sees it after zooming to their time period of interest.  Perhaps this is not possible.