# Saving Leaflet output maps WITH ICONS in R

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet

I am trying to export into png, jpg, or ANY format that can be saved, emailed, etc, a simple leaflet map with an icon made from a jpg file.  Every method I tried based on suggestions like htmlwidgets, or mapview, gives me a file with only the icon on gray background (map layer gone).   Then something weird happens.  Even if I get rid of the custom icon (from my jpeg), now I get the gray background with the blue default icon, still no map.

I have tried every solution at [How to save Leaflet in R map as png or jpg file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336898/how-to-save-leaflet-in-rstudio-map-as-png-or-jpg-file) , I at best get the icon layer but no map.

```
library(leaflet)

anna1Icon <- makeIcon(
  iconUrl = "pic.jpg",
  iconWidth = 2*31*215/230, iconHeight = 2*31,
  iconAnchorX = 2*31*215/230/2, iconAnchorY = 2*16
)

my_map <- leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lat=44, lng=-93, popup="House", icon = anna1Icon)
```

Solution attempt 1:

```
library(mapview)
mapshot(my_map, file = 'file.png')
```

Solution attempt 2:

```
library(htmlwidgets)
saveWidget(my_map, file="temp.html", selfcontained = FALSE)
webshot("temp.html", file = "output.png",
        cliprect = "viewport")
```

Help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add the statement: 
    addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap)

```
library(leaflet)

anna1Icon <- makeIcon(
  iconUrl = "pic.jpg",
  iconWidth = 2*31*215/230, iconHeight = 2*31,
  iconAnchorX = 2*31*215/230/2, iconAnchorY = 2*16
)

my_map <- leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
  addMarkers(lat=44, lng=-93, popup="House", icon = anna1Icon)


library(htmlwidgets)
saveWidget(my_map, file="temp.html", selfcontained = TRUE)
```

This is another question that has the same problem:
[saving R leaflet map as html: tiles not included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783428/saving-r-leaflet-map-as-html-tiles-not-included)