# saving R leaflet map as html: tiles not included

Tags: r, leaflet, htmlwidgets

I am trying to save an R leaflet map, using saveWidget() or outputting an rmd-file to html - as described here: [Saving leaflet output as html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110377/saving-leaflet-output-as-html)

When generating an html-file with markdown, the map will show fine in the internal rstudio viewer, *however* if I open the generated html file or the html-file produced by saveWidget() in a browser, only the circles are shown, not the tiles.

Minimal example:

````
```{r}
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)

m <- leaflet(data.frame(lat = 55.71654, lng = 12.47484))
m <-  addCircles(m, popup = "testpopup")
m <-  addTiles(m)
m
saveWidget(m, file="testmap.html")
```
````

Answer (score 6):

Add **%>% addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap)**, that worked for me. **names(providers)** gives you a list of the layers

Comment: Yes, this is the answer.

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work with `providers$CartoDB`?

Comment: What if it's not one of the provider tiles? I'm using a url to pull the tiles.

Comment: I just had a similar problem with adding a raster with `leafem:::addGeoRaster`. Worked fine in Rstudio, but not on Firefox/ Safari (not even the auto-pan worked). But on Chrome, everything seems to work. No clue why. However, I had messed around with the zIndex as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159578/raster-image-goes-below-base-layer-while-markers-stay-above-xindex-is-ignored

Answer (score -3):

Leaflet maps are good for an interactive display but not for an export. I use ggmap package to display statics maps the can be saved as PNG file.

Comment: since the question includes a reproducible example, please try to give a reproducible answer as well.

Comment: Why do you say that Leaflet maps aren't good for export? I've seen a lot of examples with leaflet maps generated in R that have been exported

Comment: They are hard to export (many lines of code) in comparison with other "statics" maps, their primary purpose is dynamic display on screen. I would say it's like trying to paper print a GIF but it's a little exaggerated :)