# How to successfully save leaflet map in a .png image?

Tags: r, linux, leaflet, maps, png

Out of geocoordinates, I want to draw simple plain points on a city map and save the output as a *.png*. I'm on **Linux Ubuntu 22.04LTS**. For the first part I found a pretty brief and straightforward `leaflet` solution.

```
library(leaflet); library(htmlwidgets); library(webshot)

m <- leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles("https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png") %>%
  setView(-.12, 51.50, zoom=13)
m$x$options <- append(m$x$options, list("zoomControl" = FALSE))
m <- m %>%
  addCircleMarkers(c(-.11, -.12, -.13), c(51.48, 51.52, 51.50),
                   radius=1, color="red")
m
```

[image]

However, the second part, saving the *.png* fails. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34672309/6574038),

```
saveWidget(m, "temp.html", selfcontained=TRUE)
webshot("temp.html", file="Rplot.png", cliprect="viewport")
```

but - using `phantomjs 2.1.1` - it gives me these errors:

```
Auto configuration failed
139740646049728:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(libproviders.so): libproviders.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
139740646049728:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
139740646049728:error:0E07506E:configuration file routines:MODULE_LOAD_DSO:error loading dso:conf_mod.c:285:module=providers, path=providers
139740646049728:error:0E076071:configuration file routines:MODULE_RUN:unknown module name:conf_mod.c:222:module=providers
Error in webshot("temp.html", file = "Rplot.png", cliprect = "viewport") : 
  webshot.js returned failure value: 1
In addition: Warning message:
In is.null(x) || is.na(x) : 'length(x) = 4 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

Using slightly older version `phantomjs 1.9.8` gives no error, but the image is completely blank. I used these sources to install `phantomjs` on Ubuntu: [1.9.8](https://chrisrmiller.com/install-phantomjs-on-ubuntu/), [2.1.1](https://tecadmin.net/install-phantomjs-on-ubuntu/). I looked into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/480764/6574038), according to which you have to install the dev version, but I didn't find it useful, because I don't know of a dev version of `phantomjs`.

I don't necessarily need a interactive `leaflet`, but I thought the dark theme looks cool and corresponds to the research topic of nocturnal crimes. Thus, I'm openish to a static solution if it looks similar (if it won't use Google).

Comment: Did you try **webshot2** (<https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webshot2/index.html>)? I never used it, I don't know, but it uses Chrome headless browser instead of phantomjs, so that could work.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent `webshot2::webshot("temp.html", file="Rplot.png", cliprect="viewport")` worked, thanks! You may put that as an answer. I had to install Google chrome, though. By chance, do you know if it is also possible to do this with the Chromium-based Brave browser?

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the new package [webshot2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webshot2/index.html), which uses the Chrome or Chromium headless browser instead of **phantomjs**.