Save a leaflet file
I use a custom package to create a graph. The final code looks a bit like this:
  stats1 <- location_isochrone_stats(address = target_address, profile = "car", breaks = seq(0, 15, 5), res = 10, legend = FALSE)

When I run the code the get a view that looks a bit like this:

I however would like to save the output of the leaflet file (png, jpg), Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336898/how-to-save-leaflet-in-r-map-as-png-or-jpg-file ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72582558/how-to-successfully-save-leaflet-map-in-a-png-image
